# NfcPlugin - WinRTError: Access is denied

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, nfc

I'm developing a Cordova app targeting win10 in Visual Studio 2015. I'm using NfcPlugin, debugging on remote tablet.

On debug get the following:

- adding proxy for NfcPlugin
- Exception calling native with command :: NfcPlugin :: init ::exception=WinRTError: Access is denied.

Can anyone help me, how can I fix this?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

It seems a permission issue.
Please try adding the following codes into `config.xml`:

```
<platform name="windows">
    <config-file target="package.appxmanifest" parent="/Package/Capabilities" versions="8.1.0">
        <DeviceCapability Name="proximity" />
    </config-file>
    <config-file target="package.appxmanifest" parent="/Package/Capabilities" versions=">8.1.0">
        <DeviceCapability Name="proximity" />
    </config-file>
</platform>
```